# Not being able to get question mark (?) as a string from sql into php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So my problem is that I have to get a URL from a SQL database and these URLs have `?` in them like `www.test.com/test2?test3`...

when I try to access that URL in PHP and I do a var_dump I only get the address
before the question mark like :

```
www.test.com/test2
```

and the address won't continue, if I remove the question mark then the whole text will be printed but of course the URL won't work without ?.

thanks in advance.

Function to get the URL from db:

```
function getUrl($absolute = false) {
    if($absolute == true) {
        return $this->url;
    } else {
        // return url path only
        $relative_path = parse_url($this->url, PHP_URL_PATH);
        $array = explode("/", $relative_path);
        unset($array[0]);
        unset($array[1]);
        return implode("/", $array);
    }
}
```

example of how I access it:

```
$linkAdress = $stream->getUrl();

echo var_dump($linkaddress)
```

Edit :

This is my first ever post here and I think that I made some rookie mistakes, a bit of clarification about this problem is that I didn't fully understand the getUrl function and this problem could have been prevented if I added true as a parameter to the function, as far as I can see this problem has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL and I have finished my project after this fix with ease, again I like to thanks the good people who helped me with my problem. this source of knowledge gives me a great sense of confidence in my future projects so thanks again.

Comment: You haven't shown any code or debugging output.

Comment: Please post actual `var_dump()` output

Comment: We can't fix your code if you don't show it to us...

Comment: Sounds like an incorrect way of using prepared statements, as ? is reserved for replacement. But without seeing ANY CODE about how you do the db interaction, its just a total guess.

Comment: _"I can't face my project leader with too many questions"_ - Why not? If something is unclear, then asking is the best way to get answers. And what do you mean by _"when I try to access that URL in PHP"_? Access how?

Comment: if your project leader doesn't want you to ask questions or isn't willing to provide any support then they're not much of a leader IMHO. I would not have much respect for that attitude. They should at least make some time for you at a good moment in the schedule which suits both of you. Or is it just you who's afraid of their reaction? Maybe it's fine really?

Comment: _"i don't know how much of company code i can share"_ ..seriously your little standard functions to read from a database or parse a URL are not going to give away any trade secrets or break any contracts, or make anyone else a millionaire at your boss's expense :-). You're not exposing the equivalent of google's search algorithms here. Don't worry about it.

Comment: look at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php   and read it, of course.....

Comment: Thanks, guys for such a fast response

Comment: The problem is your use of parse_url() - the PHP_URL_PATH option tells it not to return the ? or anything after it. And the logic which spawned the code after the call to parse_url escapes me entirely - all it does is split the URL into two parts, then delete those two parts, and then try to return those two parts. Since they're deleted, it inevitably returns nothing.

Comment: Which part of the URL are you actually trying to find? Do you just want the part(s) after the `?` (i.e. the query string or parameter list, as it's commonly known)? Also just `?test3` in the querystring is a bit unusual - normally you have parameter name followed by a value e.g. `?test3=ABC`, or multiple parameters e.g. `?test3=ABC&test4=DEF`. Have you got a better example of a URL you want to parse, and what result you want from it?

Comment: @ADyson thank you for the idea, i don't understand that part either, i haven't written these codes and they are for an old project. and i need to get the whole address wtih ? in between

Comment: If you want that, then just read `$this->url` directly. parse_url is only useful if you want to break the URL into parts

Comment: @ADyson better url example is like this:

www.test.com/video?video-id=5Aq4jqYfSPwPgRBL67reRN&player-id=DLiq99acBHs-iyusLdfzH9

Comment: If it's not accessible, then you can see from the code that setting the "absolute" paramter in the function call would mean it's returned to you directly. e.g. `$stream->getUrl(true);`

Comment: Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fcbeb657158d4a635b01173f88a5945492106ebe

Comment: @ADyson I have never tasted the milk of human kindness this sweet, thank you so much now I can move on, that was the fix. I think i didn't know how the function worked

Answer (score 1):

so it got resolved very fast by taking a look at the function and setting true in the function the code is like this

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fcbeb657158d4a635b01173f88a5945492106ebe

turns out I had to set the function to true before using echo or var_dump on the variable.

thanks to ADyson for great help.